# Simulink: fatal error: MQTTAsync.h: No such file or directory

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, mqtt, simulink

I am trying to build an MQTT system on a raspberry pi. I was studying about MQTT and read about it a lot. I found a set of MQTT blocks in the Simulink Raspberry Pi Hardware Support Package that I assumed I could directly use. I configured an MQTT server and got all the right credentials and everything but I am now stuck on one part that has left me stumped.

I keep getting this error saying that "fatal error: MQTTAsync.h: No such file or directory". I have looked a lot trying to find anything that might help me but I couldn't. I don't know where to get the necessary files that I need or if there is any solution to sort this. I'm sharing the entire snippet of the error if that is of any help. Thanks in advance.

I apologize I'm not able to get to the whole error into a code block

```
Error executing command "touch -c /home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Users/User/Documents/MATLAB/Project_RPi_ert_rtw/*.*;make  -f Project_RPi.mk all MATLAB_WORKSPACE="/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a" -C /home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Users/User/Documents/MATLAB/Project_RPi_ert_rtw LC_ALL=C". Details:

STDERR: In file included from /home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2022a/toolbox/realtime/targets/linux/src/MW_MQTT.c:5:
/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2022a/toolbox/realtime/targets/linux/include/MW_MQTT.h:49:10: fatal error: MQTTAsync.h: No such file or directory
 #include <MQTTAsync.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Project_RPi.mk:411: MW_MQTT.c.o] Error 1

STDOUT: make: Entering directory '/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Users/User/Documents/MATLAB/Project_RPi_ert_rtw'
gcc -c -MMD -MP -MF"MW_MQTT.c.dep" -MT"MW_MQTT.c.o" -O2  -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -DMW_CAN_BITRATE=500000 -DMW_CAN_ALLOWALLMSGS=1 -DMW_NUM_MQTT_SUBSCRIBE=1 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DTERMFCN=1 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DMAT_FILE=0 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0  -DTID01EQ=0 -D__linux__ -DARM_PROJECT -D_USE_TARGET_UDP_ -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DRT -DMODEL=Project_RPi -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DMODEL_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_SFCNS=0 -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Users/User/Documents/MATLAB -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2022a/toolbox/realtime/targets/linux/include -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2022a/toolbox/target/shared/svd/include -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2022a/toolbox/realtime/targets/raspi/include -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Users/User/Documents/MATLAB/Project_RPi_ert_rtw -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Program_Files/MATLAB/R2022a/extern/include -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Program_Files/MATLAB/R2022a/simulink/include -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Program_Files/MATLAB/R2022a/rtw/c/src -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Program_Files/MATLAB/R2022a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Program_Files/MATLAB/R2022a/rtw/c/ert -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Program_Files/MATLAB/R2022a/toolbox/coder/rtiostream/src/utils -I/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Program_Files/MATLAB/R2022a/toolbox/target/codertarget/rtos/inc -o "MW_MQTT.c.o" "/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2022a/toolbox/realtime/targets/linux/src/MW_MQTT.c"
make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2022a/C/Users/User/Documents/MATLAB/Project_RPi_ert_rtw'
```

Comment: Have you installed the development files? (with something like `sudo apt-get install libpaho-mqtt-dev` assuming you are running Raspbian; sorry don't have a working Pi to test on at the moment).

Comment: I did install paho-mqtt using pip on both the pi and my windows pc. I scanned through the folders but didn't find any header files. And it didn't work after this either

Comment: "install paho-mqtt using pip" that will install the python client; the error you are having relates to the `C` client which is totally separate (`MQTTAsync.h` is a C header file).

Comment: Ohh that worked! Thanks so much! For anyone else who faces this issues this [website](https://bytesofgigabytes.com/raspberrypi/mqtt-c-client-raspberry-pi/) provides step by step instructions for how to install the library. Thanks @Brits

Comment: I would be a little cautions following those instructions; they suggest retrieving code from a very old (2018!) fork of [paho.mqtt.C](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c) (the main repo will contain a considerable number of fixes). You should also be able to install prebuilt libraries with the command I provided above.